# MySQL query cannot figure out how to execute

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

suppose i have table "test":

```
user    |    category    |    bank    |    cash
------------------------------------------------
aaa     |    cat1        |    TBC     |    10
aaa     |    cat2        |    TBC     |    20
aaa     |    cat2        |    TBC     |    30
aaa     |    cat1        |    VTB     |    20
bbb     |    cat1        |    TBC     |    10
bbb     |    cat2        |    TBC     |    20
bbb     |    cat2        |    TBC     |    30
```

I need query that will group users, categories, banks, and sum up cash like this:

```
user_gr |    category_gr |    bank_gr |    cash_gr
------------------------------------------------
aaa     |    cat1        |    TBC     |    10
aaa     |    cat2        |    TBC     |    50
aaa     |    cat1        |    VTB     |    20
bbb     |    cat1        |    TBC     |    10
bbb     |    cat2        |    TBC     |    50
```

I apologize if I explain my problem poorly, or if I ask too much. Any help will be appreciated. I tried to search my question, but I don't know how to type my request properly, all results I found did not match my request. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grouping by `user`, `category` and `bank` and then applying the `SUM()` aggregate on cash should do the trick?

**Query**

```
 SELECT user AS user_gr, 
        category AS category_gr, 
        bank AS bank_gr, 
        SUM(cash) AS  cash_gr
   FROM test
GROUP BY user, category, bank;
```

Comment: Both answers are correct, I just ticked this one, because it matches the request more correctly. By the way, you should edit last line as code. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is called an aggregate query or a summary query. The key to your research is `GROUP BY`.

Something like this should work:

```
 SELECT user, category, bank, SUM(cash) AS cash_gr
   FROM test
  GROUP BY user, category, bank
```

Honestly, this is basic SQL. You probably should read one of the many books or do one of the excellent online tutorials, especially if you're handling other peoples' money.

Comment: Thank you. I just did not know that it was possible to group by multiple columns. Also i do not manage other peoples' money, it is just a school project, and all knowledge of MySQL i have, is gained from this site by searching questions and reading peoples' comments and solutions. Thank you.